# A question regarding Brahmana marriage?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, marriage, manu-smriti

Namaste,
In Manu Smriti and Mahabharata it is said that a Brahmana may first marry a Brahmana Girl then a Kshatriya a Vaishya and a Sudra girl in this order.But we see in Mahabharata and Ramayana that sages married Kshatriya Girls first(Princesses)..Isn't it contravention of law?
Or is there any clause that allows Brahmana man to marry a Kshatriya girl directly?

Answer (score 0):

That verse is not reality marriage. What it means:
Brahmanaha paramapurushasya mukham aaseeth.
Since compared to face of God and the priesthood of marriage ritual carnated towards other varnas, the bridegroom of other 3 varnas are attached in mind towards God through the Brahmana priest.

This is compared and cited as married to
Similar to saying scientist married to science does not mean his desire or lust or kaama is on science but scientist has propounded the science object.
Here, in manu smriti after agni suktham a Brahmana, of his holiness propounds bondage between a sincere man to sincere woman of respective varnas.

Please take good literal meaning and not just mere translation.

In other words, those women who loose their husbands accidentally or in caste hate crimes or wars at later stages think God as their husband. Does it mean God married the affected females one by one physically? No, but females are married to God literally.